# How to download facebook report using Insights API Asynchronous Jobs?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-java-api

Hi I'am new to facebook marketing API. I want to download account complete report in csv format for which I am using Insights API Asynchronous Jobs , Using which I am able to get "report_run_id" and after that I made api request for [this link](https://www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report/?report_run_id=XXXXX&name=reports&format=csv) .Its giving wrong response. Can anybody help me how can download report in csv format.code which i tried is:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();    
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report/?report_run_id=279445242544715&name=reports&format=csv")
  .get()
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
if(response.isSuccessful()){
 String resposes=response.body().string();
}
```

Comment: You found a solution on how to do it with the API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give examples using curl, but you should be able to translate these to javascript easily.

Using the `report_run_id`, you can query the completeness of the async query, for example:

```
curl -G \
  -d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/1000002
```

This should eventually give you a completion of 100%:

```
{
  "id": "6044775548468",
  "account_id": "1010035716096012",
  "time_ref": 1459788928,
  "time_completed": 1459788990,
  "async_status": "Job Completed",
  "async_percent_completion": 100
}
```

You then need to query the report_run_id for with the insights edge:

```
curl -G \
  -d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/<YOUR_REPORT_RUN_ID>/insights
```

Comment: Great, Worked for me!

Comment: Is there any way to get a CSV export via the API?

Comment: hi guys, where to find the access token ? I am struggling to find the access token here.